# Unable to insert image/figure

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I am trying to insert a .png image here. It's showing me this error "Not in outer par mode". I have tried changing .jpeg extension to .png. Still not working.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Fat.jpeg}
    \caption{Visceral and subcutaneous fat obesity}
    \label{fig: fat}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please avoid screenshots and type both LaTeX code and error messages properly using the tools provided by this site.

Comment: @Miyase I have updated the question

Comment: @Community I have updated the question

Comment: Thank you, but your LaTeX code is incomplete and not compilable. Please provide a Minimal Working Example so that people can see what you're doing and find the problem. You can also remove the screenshots.

Comment: You should usually leave out the suffix part (i.e. without .png, .jpg etc.) That said, there is a `(` instead of `{` in your caption.

Comment: @Ingmar Oh, that was a mistake in writing here. I corrected it. There is no (

Comment: BTW, the problem is that figure must be in outer par mode.  \includegraphics couldn't care less.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a full MWE, since the comment thread is getting very long again. This should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Visceral and subcutaneous fat obesity}
    \label{fig: fat}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Try this, and tell us (why) it's (not) working.

Comment: I have just tried this, still not working. Same error.

The whole code is very long. This is where I am using the figure environment.

> https://pastebin.com/zz7hjvYX

Comment: Code in Ingmar answer for sure is not source of your error(s).  Please edit question and in it  provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete, compilable document, which reproduce your problem. You can make them from your document so that from it you strip out of all not relevant parts of document.